# GoogleSignIn iOS - Disable SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, google-signin, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm developing an enterprise application for one of our clients that utilises the GoogleSignIn SDK an a login option.

During development, I was surprised to see that support for the `SFSafariViewController` had been added meaning that I could streamline my login process by sharing Safari cookies.

This was all great until the client raised a critical issue being that once a user logs into the app (via Google and `SFSafariViewController`), they could log out of our application (including the GoogleSignIn SDK (see below))

```
func signOut() {
    ...
    let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    signIn.signOut()
}
```

However the user remains signed into their Google account via Safari. Something that would be **extremely** helpful on a personal device but i've been informed that there is the potential for 20 people on a single site to be using a single device.

I've looked at setting `allowsSignInWithBrowser` and/or `allowsSignInWithWebView` to `false` however I cannot get it so that the SDK will use only a web view (such as `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`) where we can ensure that credentials will only be persisted within the application.

Is there such functionality to achieve this that I am missing? I think it could be quite critical in some use cases that such configuration is available.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @George: Nope, I've moved jobs since then but just checked and they never worked around it :/